# React Navigation disables Animated API?

Tags: react-native

Has anyone ever had any experience with using the React Native Animated API with React Native? I am noticing any sort of Animated Element I put into my Views do not seem to work.
However when spinning up basically a blank project everything I tried work. The only thing left for me to think is somehow animation is disabled in StackNavigators?

Has anyone run into this before?

I am using React-Native Splash Screen
But based on my dependencies I don't see how any of these would somehow disable the animated api..

```
 "react-native": "0.49.2",
    "react-native-action-button": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-camera": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^3.0.3",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-spinkit": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.4.2",
    "react-native-writebox": "^1.0.9",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.13",
    "react-navigation-slide-from-right-transition": "^1.0.4"
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post the exact problem, some source code, etc.

Answer (score 1):

none of these things has no bussiness with Animated API so i suggest you to give us your code to see whats wrong

but you still can read animated API again : 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html
and if you need some video tutorial you can watch : 
https://egghead.io/lessons/react-animate-styles-of-a-react-native-view-with-animated-timing

Answer (score 1):

According to the maintainers' response on [this issue](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2799), it doesn't disable the Animated API. They say they are using it successfully.

However, I have been unsuccessful getting `Animated.timing` to work properly in `react-navigation`, which is how I came across this question.